# "Merge" PODs into one

Tags: c++, inheritance, reflection, structured-bindings, standard-layout

Is there a way to *compose* (or *merge, aggregate*) PODs between them ? One intuitive solution:

```
struct Base1 { int i; };
struct Base2 { char c; };

struct Derived : Base1, Base2 {};

// in a more generalized way
// template <class... Ts> struct Aggregate : Ts... {};
```

Except, we lose something:

```
int main()
{
    Derived d {42, 'c'}; // OK
    auto [i, c] = d; // Error
    static_assert(std::is_standard_layout_v<Derived>); // Error
}
```

I see we could end up with some ambiguousities, conflicts, between the merged base classes. But it would be pretty nice to merge PODs into one. The result I try to achieve:

```
struct Expected { int i; char c; }; // I want Derived to behave exactly like this
```

Am I in the realm of reflection? Should I end up using macros?

Comment: There are ways to get this to work by writing your own tuple access but the type you're making is [non-standard-layout](https://eel.is/c++draft/class#prop-3.7)

Comment: Did you want the resulting aggregate to also be a POD?

Comment: @Eljay Actually I don't care if the derived struct is a POD or not, it takes the same size. I'd achieve the structured bindings feature at least. In a generic way if possible, i.e. for `template <class... Ts> struct Aggregate : Ts... {};`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we

> don't care if the derived struct is a POD or not

, the task is pretty simple with [`Boost.PFR`](https://github.com/boostorg/pfr) - just convert your PODs to tuples and concatenate them:

```cpp
template<typename... Ts> using Merge = decltype(std::tuple_cat(
    boost::pfr::structure_to_tuple(std::declval<Ts>())...
));
```

A simple test:

```cpp
int main() {
    struct Base1 { int i, j; };
    struct Base2 { char c; };
    using Expected = Merge<Base1, Base2>;
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<Expected, std::tuple<int, int, char>>);
    Expected expected{42, 1337, 'c'};
    auto&& [i, j, c] = expected;
}
```